# install_driver(mysql) failed: Attempt to reload DBD/mysql.pm aborted error in Bugzilla installation on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, perl, bugzilla, activestate

I have installed Bugzilla on my windows system using this https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/windows.html link.

Firstly, clone the https://github.com/bugzilla/bugzilla.git link to install bugzilla on system.

```
git clone https://github.com/bugzilla/bugzilla.git
```

After That install Perl and its required module using [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/Products/ActivePerl/).

```
C:\Perl64\bin>perl -v

This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2018, Larry Wall

Binary build 0000 [a2725156] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Feb  9 2021 19:51:54
```

Now for the database i have use MySql for which i have used below version

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.26    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and in that I have created a new MySQL user for Bugzilla to use. Run run the following command in mysql command-line client :

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'bugs'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bugs';
mysql> SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bugs'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Also updated the localconfig file also

```
$db_driver = 'mysql';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'bugs';
$db_pass = 'bugs';
$db_port = 3306;
```

After setting up all configuation, Now when I run checksetup.pl it produce the following error.

```
    Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.050

install_driver(mysql) failed: Attempt to reload DBD/mysql.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 356) line 3.

 at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 1328
```

**Can anyone help with this issue.**

**Note:** Also, I have checked various articles available on internet as well as on stackOverflow however it didn't resolve my issue.

.

Comment: *"... using ActiveState"* : Maybe you could also try with [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/) ?

Comment: Are you able to load the module? What is the output of running `perl -MDBD::mysql -e1` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have run the command its give me below output
C:\bugzilla>perl -MDBD::mysql -e1
Can't load 'C:/Perl64/site/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.dll' for module DBD::mysql: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
  at -e line 0.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: Ok, it seems the module is not properly installed? Can you try to reinstall it?

Comment: I tried to install Active Perl 5.34.0 on Windows 10 now, but it seems it does not support `DBD::mysql` (from the Active Platform UI). It has `DBD::Pg` and `DBD::SQLite`, but not `DBD::mysql`. How did you install `DBD::mysql` with Active Perl?

Comment: @HåkonHægland 
we can istall using cpan command
C:\Perl64\bin>cpan

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.20)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install DBD::mysql
Reading 'C:\Users\sharma_l\AppData\Local\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 20 Sep 2021 04:55:39 GMT
DBD::mysql is up to date (4.050).

Comment: Can you try force reinstall it? Try run `cpan -f -i DBD::mysql` ...

Comment: it is giving me error.

Comment: Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 12.

Comment: Can you please upload the complete output to e.g. pastebin? Then provide a link here

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZiaNVw0t

Comment: Yes the log output shows *"Couldn't find your C compiler."*. It means that it probably has not configured a C compiler. I think it should work more easily with Strawberry Perl since it has a C compiler. It also has `DBD::mysql` preinstalled so you do not need to install it. Can you try install Strawberry Perl ?

Comment: Ok Thanks let me try installing Strawberry Perl.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I used strawberry Perl and setup Bugzilla properly but then also facing an issue that it is not loading its UI.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266719/bugzilla-ui-not-working-after-setup-giving-error-your-web-server-could-not-fetc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.